# Microsoft Lists - Conditional formatting based on number of days to Employee start date

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I'm new to MS Lists or sharepoint Lists.

I have a list of new starter employees to prepare their equipment.

I need to change the formatting according to:

If Type of Collection is "couriered" change background color to light blue.
If "Collected" change background color to light green.
If 14 days before or equal Start Date and Type of Collection is "To be collected" change background color to light yellow and font to bold.
If 14 days before or equal Start Date and Type of Collection is "To be couriered" change background color to light pink and font to bold.

Could you please assist?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Format current view -> Advanced mode -> Add following codes.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "additionalRowClass": "=if([$TypeofCollection] == 'Couriered', 'sp-css-backgroundColor-blueBackground37', if([$TypeofCollection] == 'Collected', 'sp-css-backgroundColor-successBackground50', if(([$TypeofCollection] == 'To be collected')&&([$DueDate] <= @now-1209600000),'sp-css-backgroundColor-warningBackground50', if(([$TypeofCollection] == 'To be couriered')&&([$DueDate] <= @now-1209600000),'sp-field-severity--severeWarning', ''))))"
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your assistance.

Is there another function other than "@now"? like "@date"!!!

I want to make the color change 14 days ahead of the date entered in due date.

@now won't take the specified date in the cell. It will take the current date that the list is being viewed.

Maybe I'm wrong but I found and tried these before I asked the question here and they didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To change the background color and font formatting of a list item in Microsoft Lists or SharePoint lists, you can use conditional formatting rules. Here's how you can set this up:

1. Go to the list that you want to apply the formatting to, and click the "Format current view" button in the top right corner of the page.
2. In the "Format current view" pane that appears on the right side of the page, click the "Add a rule" button.
3. In the "Add a rule" pane that appears, enter a name for the rule in the "Rule name" field.
4. In the "Rule criteria" section, select the column that you want to use to trigger the formatting (e.g. "Type of Collection" or "Start Date").
5. Select the operator that you want to use to compare the column value to (e.g. "equals", "is greater than or equal to", etc.).
6. Enter the value that you want to compare the column value to (e.g. "Collected", "14 days before or equal", etc.).
7. In the "Formatting options" section, select the formatting options that you want to apply when the rule criteria are met. For example, you can select the "Background color" option and choose a color, or select the "Font weight" option and choose "Bold".
8. Click the "Save" button to save the rule.

[image]

You can repeat these steps to create additional rules for the other formatting scenarios that you described.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Denis and Emily for helping me with this.

I'm unsure if I've found the correct answer but it's working for now:

I used Emily's code and modified it for the format (BG color and font), but what made it work is to change the - to +

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "additionalRowClass": "=if([$TypeofCollection] == 'Couriered', 'sp-css-backgroundColor-BgSage sp-css-color-BlackText', if([$TypeofCollection] == 'Collected', 'sp-css-backgroundColor-BgMintGreen sp-css-color-BlackText', if(([$TypeofCollection] == 'To be collected')&&([$StartingDate] <= @now+1209600000),'sp-css-backgroundColor-BgGold sp-field-bold sp-css-color-BrownText', if(([$TypeofCollection] == 'To be couriered')&&([$StartingDate] <= @now+1209600000),'sp-css-backgroundColor-BgPeach sp-field-bold sp-css-color-RedText', ''))))"
}
```

Below is the output:

[image]